# Excel file created using EPPlus has 'invalid format'

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007, epplus

I'm using EPPlus on .Net 4.0 using C#.
Here is my code:

```
        FileInfo output = new FileInfo("myFile.xlsx");
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage( output ))
        {
            package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TEST");

            var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["TEST"];
            sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "TEST";

            package.Save();
        }
```

I get the following error when I open the file using Microsoft Office Excel 2007.
"myFile.xlsx: file format is not valid".

Attached is the error image.

[image: Error]

Comment: What's happening, if you change format to .xls?

Comment: sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "TEST if it's copy&paste, so you forget **"** sign before **;**.

Comment: Changing it to .xls has the same error.

Comment: Is myfile.xlsx an existing file?  Have you tried opening it on another machine or newer version of Excel?

Comment: I have tested this on another machine, but not with a newer version of Excel as I want this to work on Excel 2007 - I believe EPPlus supports 2007. It has failed with the same error.  I have downloaded the dll which I downloaded and added it as a reference in my Visual Studio project as instructed in their site. I am getting this error however.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the confusion - I was using a wrong assembly for reference. Feel like a fool. Sorry. Thanks for the attention given.